# flutter_blue_plus 1.20.8でペアリングとボンディングしないように変更する方法

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

flutter_blue_plus 1.20.8ライブラリを使用してAndroid端末同士でBLE接続してるのですが，ペアリングとボンディングしないようにしたいです．flutter_blue_plus.dartで使用されているbluetooth.device.dartのcreateBond関数をコメントアウトして，ボンディングしないようにはしたと思うのですが，今だBLE接続した際に画像のペアリングのポップアップが表示されます。

このポップアップが出ないようにするには，flutter_blue_plus.dartで使用されているどのコードを変更すればいいのかご教示ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: ペアリング]